# cannot declare to be of abstract type

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, abstract, pure-virtual

I got the following error:

```
error: cannot declare variable 'b' to be of abstract type 'B'
note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'B'
note: virtual bool Serializable::eq(const QString&) const
      virtual bool eq( const QString & qs) const = 0;
                   ^
note: virtual bool Serializable::eq(const Serializable*) const
      virtual bool eq( const Serializable * o) const = 0;
                   ^
```

on this code:

```
class Serializable {
public:
    virtual  bool eq( const QString & qs) const = 0;
    virtual  bool eq( const Serializable * o) const = 0;
};

class JSONSerializable : public Serializable {
public:
    virtual  QString toJSON( void) const = 0;

    virtual  bool eq( const QString & qs) const {
                 return toJSON() == qs;
             }
    virtual  bool eq( const Serializable * o) const {
                 return eq( (( JSONSerializable *) o)->toJSON());
             }
};

class A : public Serializable {  };

class B : public A,
          public JSONSerializable {
public:
    virtual  QString toJSON( void) const {
                 return QString( "test!");
             }
};

…
B b;
qDebug() << b.toJSON();
…
```

I understand that it's because of the pure virtual methods or/and multiple inheritance. This error really makes me cry. How can I make it dissappear? I would be very appreciate for some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `B` inherits the abstract class `Serializable` twice:

- Once through its base class `A`, and
- Once more through its other base class `JSONSerializable`

As the result, you must override the two pure virtuals of `Serializable` twice.

Since you are asking the question about `B`'s remaining abstract, my understanding is that you did not intend things to be that way: you wanted `B` to inherit `Serializable` only once, as if it were an interface, and use `JSONSerializable`'s implementation to "mix in" additional functionality. If that is the case, you need to inherit `Serializable` *virtually*, like this:

```
class Serializable {
public:
    virtual  bool eq( const QString & qs) const = 0;
    virtual  bool eq( const Serializable * o) const = 0;
};

class JSONSerializable : virtual public Serializable {
public:
    virtual  QString toJSON( void) const = 0;

    virtual  bool eq( const string & qs) const {
                 return toJSON() == qs;
             }
    virtual  bool eq( const Serializable * o) const {
                 return eq(dynamic_cast<const JSONSerializable*>(o)->toJSON());
             }
};

class A : virtual public Serializable {  };

class B : virtual public A,
          public JSONSerializable {
public:
    virtual  QString toJSON( void) const {
                 return QString( "test!");
             }
};
```

The added `virtual` keyword instructs the compiler that you want only one "copy" of `Serializable` base to be included in your class `B`.

This change fixes the problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/4QrAbt)).

Comment: Thank you, @dasblinkenlight, it helped! You were right, I tried to make mix in functionality.